# How can I position a block of text to be centered vertically 1/3 down a page?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I have this XAML that I am currently using but it's just a start as I am stuck on how to do this.  What I would like is for the text of Msg1 to be centered 1/3 from the top and 2/3 from the bottom of my screen like this:

```
#####################  <-
#                   #
#                   #  1/3
#                   #
#       ABC         #  <-
#                   #
#                   #
#                   #
#                   #  2/3
#                   #
#                   #
#                   #
#                   #
#####################  <-

<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
      xmlns:template="clr-namespace:Japanese.Templates" 
      x:Class="Japanese.Views.Phrases.Xaml.NoCards" 
      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="60" >  
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Msg1}" 
           HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Can anyone suggest how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is quite easy actually you do it like this :

```
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
  xmlns:template="clr-namespace:Japanese.Templates" 
  x:Class="Japanese.Views.Phrases.Xaml.NoCards" 
  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >  
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Label Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Msg1}" 
       XAlign="Center"
       HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
       VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
 </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your grid definition as mentioned above by @G.hakim or similar to below, so that you will be dividing your grid to 3 parts. First part you can achieve your requirement..

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```